# Can Python list comprehension be used in this use-case?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Recently I had to traverse a tree, starting from an arbitrary node up to its root. I wrote something along the lines of

```py
breadcrumbs = []
while node is not None:
    breadcrumbs.append(node.get_text())
    node = node.get_parent()
```

It has occured to me that it looks a lot like an ugly implementation of list construction that uses

```py
result = []
while node is not None:
    result.append(node.get_text())
    node = node.next()
```

instead of the more idiomatic list comprehension

```py
result = [node.get_text() for node in nodes]
```

This made me wonder whether there is a more idiomatic way of constructing a list from my tree traversal. For completeness (and because the above excerpts are mainly pseudo-code), here is the actual code I used:

```py
model, treeiter = self.treeview.get_selection().get_selected()
breadcrumbs = []
while treeiter is not None:
    breadcrumbs.append(model.get_value(treeiter, self.COL_TEXT))
    treeiter = model.iter_parent(treeiter)
path = '/'.join(reversed(breadcrumbs))
```

For context, the first line calls [Gtk.TreeSelection.get_selected](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/interfaces/TreeSelection.html#Gtk.TreeSelection.get_selected) (one of its return values is called `iter` in the API but has nothing to do with Python iterators). My code creates a string from the path selected by the user, e.g., `"A/b/2"` in the example below:

```
+- A
|  |- a
|  \- b
|     |- 1
|     \- 2       <- selected element
\- B
   |- c
   \- d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are true, the tree structure you are using is not very pythonic. But, you can easily turn it to a more pythonic solution using home-made [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator).

For instance, to traverse the parents (or ancestors) you can define a `iter_parents` function like this:

```py
def iter_parents(node):
    while node is not None:
        yield node
        node = node.get_parent()
```

With this in hand, you can build the breadcrumbs like this:

```py
breadcrumbs = [node.get_text() for node in iter_parents(branch)]
```

Here is a small demo:

```py
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        self._text = text
        self._parent = parent

    def get_text(self):
        return self._text

    def get_parent(self):
        return self._parent


branch = Node("c", Node("b", Node("a")))

breadcrumbs = [node.get_text() for node in iter_parents(branch)]

print(breadcrumbs)
# -> ['c', 'b', 'a']
```

For `node.next()` you can define a `iter_next()` generator the same way.

**edit**

Use `reverse` to reverse the list, for instance:

```py
breadcrumbs = [node.get_text() for node in iter_parents(branch)]
breadcrumbs.reverse()

print(breadcrumbs)
# -> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can wrap your while loop in a generator like this:

```
def get_parents(node):
    while node is not None:
        yield node
        node = node.get_parent()
```

Then you can use:

```
result = [node.get_text() for node in get_parents(nodes)]
```

Comment: It seems that we have the same idea at the same time…